# data structures/ Classes for RNA & DNA

Tags: object-oriented, bioinformatics

In bioinformatics they study biological data. I have seen [codes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dna-protein-python-3/) dealing with DNA sequences. However, they are treated as string literal. I was wondering if there were data structures or classes in OOP sense ( even partial representation) for [RNA and DNA](https://www.thoughtco.com/dna-versus-rna-608191).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CS

Comment: A string *is* a data structure  / class.  I'm not sure what kind of answer you are hoping for or what the motivation for asking is.

Comment: @D.W., it does make sense to use a specialized tool for DNA/RNA, there are just four symbols, and the words are often millions of base (pairs) in length.